# Extension of `org.jooq.Converter<Any?, Long?>` in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I'm writing a converter for JOOQ  which extends `Converter<Any?, Long?>` in Kotlin. It requires me to override several functions one of which is

```
override fun fromType(): Class<Any?> = ...
```

The question is: In Kotlin how do I get the type of `Any?`? The following does not work:

```
override fun fromType(): Class<Any?> = Any?::class.java
```

Answer (score 1):

From the JVM's point of the view, there is no separate "class" that represents `Any?`, as opposed to `Any`. `Any?` and `Any` are all just `java.lang.Object`. The JVM does not care about nullability.

So if you are to return "a `Class` object representing the class `Any?`", you can just return what is known as `Object.class` in Java, or `Any::class.java` in Kotlin.

The type of `Any::class.java` is `Class<Any>`, but that doesn't matter because generic types are erased anyway. What matters is that the `Class` object representing `Any` and the one representing `Any?` are the same object. Therefore, it is safe to do an unchecked cast:

```
override fun fromType() = Any::class.java as Class<Any?>
```